# Dereferencing an element pointed to by a NULL pointer

Tags: c, pointers, null, segmentation-fault, dereference

I'm working with a priority queue, but I seem to be getting a segmentation fault at `(*ppFront)->pNext = NULL`. In this case `pNext` is the front of the queue with `pPrev` pointing to the rest of the list. I don't  why this could be an error if `(*ppFront)->pNext` should always be NULL as the front of the list.

```
WaitlistEntry dequeue( PQNode** ppFront ){
    WaitlistEntry ret;
    if(*ppFront == NULL)
        return;
    PQNode *temp = *ppFront;
    ret.iPriority = (*ppFront)->info.iPriority;
    ret.iStudentID = (*ppFront)->info.iStudentID;
    *ppFront = (*ppFront)->pPrev;
    (*ppFront)->pNext = NULL;
    free(temp);
    return ret;
}
```

I have an `enqueue` method that I tested separately and it creates the actual queue without problems, but I am having trouble deleting the front of the queue. This is my error.

```
Invalid write of size 8
   at 0x40134D: dequeue( enroll.c:317)
   by 0x4011AA: dropStudent(enroll.c:251)
   by 0x400D32: main (enroll:111)
address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I've googled and I think I am trying to dereference a null pointer(?).

Comment: `*ppFront = (*ppFront)->pPrev; (*ppFront)->pNext = NULL;` --> `*ppFront = (*ppFront)->pNext; if(*ppFront) (*ppFront)->pPrev = NULL;` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I realized I was always assuming the queue would have multiple elements. I didn't consider a check for thee case of only having one element in the queue. I was trying to dereference a null pointer.